# WAR automaticly deployment Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, vps, tomcat8

I have installed tomcat on my VPS now I want to automatically deploy war files on my local pc to Tomcat and everytime that i had new version of the war, old war is removed and replaced by the new version. thanks

Comment: Thanks for telling us what you want but, is there even a question here?

Comment: what do you mean automatically, each time you are creating a war, you have to FTP it to webapps folder of your VPS tomcat.

Also couldn't understand creating new version of war?? are you using any IDE or packaging your code using command line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try Jenkins, it is used for automating the build and deployment of java projects.

https://jenkins.io/

Comment: thnk u so much I deployed jenkins in tomcat server , i tried to add maven project by specifying  maven_home  in global Tools configuration but when i click on  new item  i can't find maven project  as an option i restart jenkins but without result .

I use Tomcat 8 and jenkins 2.19.1

So how could i add  Maven  as an item type ?